# PHP SQL Why does this give me an error without details

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hi I'm trying to insert data in my database. But I keep on getting the same error for example:

`Error: INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('fff', '$2y$10$YUd1AErIj4RGRnjkFkYlkOn.s9OV62sq8.HVGO2jeE8dSthpgp6ey');`

without any details which is very frustrating. I'm new to PHP and SQL so it's not the best written code ever and I know I should use prepared statements.

```
<?php
require_once '../connection/connection.php';
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ezrab
 * Date: 3/14/2018
 * Time: 5:40 PM
 */
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//var_dump($hashed_password);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($username) || !empty($password)) {
        if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z ]*$/', $username) || preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z ]*$/', $password)) {
            $hashPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$hashPwd');";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Worked!";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        } else {
            echo "You can't use certain characters.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You have to fill in all fields.";
    }
} else {
    echo "THOU SHALL NOT PASS!";
}
$conn->close();
```

**EDIT:** Added my connection.php file for more information.

```
<?php
$servername = "-----";
$username = "-----";
$password = "------";
$dbname = "------";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Not sure but I don't think you need `=== TRUE`.

Comment: @Uueerdo According to w3schools you need to format it like this.

Comment: "I know I should use prepared statements".  So do it right from the beginning.  There is no reason for doing it this way.  You're just creating more work for yourself.  That said, my guess is that your `password` column isn't big enough.

Comment: Does the data show up in the table (as though the insert went through) despite the error?

Comment: @Uueerdo No the data doesn't show up so there is a real error.

Comment: What is the real error?

Comment: The real error is that OP is using w3schools as a resource, which is leading him down the wrong path without prepared statements, and over-complicated syntax....

Comment: @cale_b What is 'OP'?

Comment: OP = "original poster".  (In this case, that's you, @Ezrab_).

Comment: @cale_b: regarding your W3schools comment, do you know of a good resource for beginners to start on?  I learned by doing and reading many scattered resources, but it would be nice if we could suggest a simple and safe starting point for newbies.

Comment: @cale_b In my opinion w3schools explains the code much easier for starting students (just like me) to understand them better then the PHP manual. I understand people don't want to see newbies like me make these mistakes but that's the process of learning my friend.

Comment: @cale_b `catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }` isn't much better than what you get at w3scools. OPs main problem is: not using proper error handling.

Comment: IMO, starting at a _known_ wrong way of doing things is _not_ "the process of learning".  That's setting yourself up for errors, failure, and getting hacked.

Comment: @PatrickQ Okay then we have different visions of the process of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Take

```
$conn->close();
```

out of connection.php and problem should be solved

You were opening and then immediately closing the connection before a query could be made

Comment: Not having enough reputation to post comments is not an excuse to post non-answers as answers.  The site has rules and restrictions, please adhere to them.

Comment: You sound fun. This is a valid answer, just prefacing I would put it as a comment. Heaven forbid this turns our to be the correct answer!

Comment: Yeah they were the same however still getting the same issue.

Comment: Have you updated the vairables in your script above? I'll edit my answer now with a suggested solution

Comment: Answers are not conjectures.  You do not suspect and guess in an answer.  The fact that you even acknowledged this originally shows that you knew you didn't have enough for an answer and were getting around the restrictions currently on your account.  And FYI, reusing the variable names would have no impact.  The connection has already been made.

Comment: The connection `$conn` is already established prior to the re-assignment.

Comment: @Rockhopper Just like Patrick states, they don't have to be different I changed them but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: My bad hadn't thought about that. Can you please also post the contents of the connection.php file just so we can double check it? Also it is best practice to not reuse variable names as a side note

Comment: you really did not have to copy and paste whole of OP's code. Also you have just successfully condoned SQL injection

Comment: OMG! I am trying to help with an answer chill dudes! I actually edited the variables so they were unique. SQL injection has alreayd been covered above. Seriously what is with this site and jumping on people making an honest effort to help???

Comment: @Rockhopper - please listen to the feedback.  The site is _not_ just about providing answers - it's about providing answers _to future visitors_.  **No question** that is open to SQL injection should receive an answer that does not address the SQL injection problem.  **No answer** should just be a guess.  Maybe you should slow down and take the time to read the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) part of StackOverflow.

Comment: Jumping back to the original problem is that error message correct? In that you were trying to insert fff as the username? Seems odd unless you were testing is all.

Comment: Sorry was my answer wrong @cale_b?? Or did I solve the problem whilst you lot argued with me?

Comment: @Rockhopper your solution worked! Guys let's just leave it like this for now it works that's the only thing that I wanted! ;)

Comment: I retracted my DV as the current version is correct.  However, please do take the feedback in these comments to heart.  Answers are _not_ for guesses and obtaining further information form the OP.  That's what comments are for.  As long as you follow the rules, you _will_ be able to post comments eventually.